# WebView displays a blank page

Tags: java, android

Below is my code,
but I use "https://google.com" is successfully displaying the page
the problems is html5 or ssl?
thanks all

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    setContentView(myWebView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("myURL");

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the necessity of  this `setContentView(myWebView);`??

Comment: solved problem ! thankyou very much!

Comment: Okay let me answer it down below and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
 setContentView(myWebView);
```

Its not necessary!